# Is there a way to change settings in Nexus 4 so that we should enter Passkey before Bluetooth pairing?

Tags: bluetooth, android-bluetooth, nexus-4

In Nexus 4 while pairing Bluetooth, it doesn't ask user to enter the Passkey. Instead it shows a Passkey in both device.

Kindly let me know if there is any advance settings, so that only once the user enters his own Passkey it should connect.

Comment: I have the impression you want to (miss) use that "passkey" as a security challenge. But that is not what it is meant for. The (very weak) security against unauthorized connections lies within the pairing challenge, the connection must be actively accepted on the host side once. Afterwards bluetooth allows devices to reconnect without any hassle.

Comment: Thank You. But the problem it that while connecting, it doesn't ask for user defined passkey. Instead the mobile generates its own pass key while connecting both devices.

Comment: It reuses the key used during the initial pairing.

Comment: HI... I am trying to automate Bluetooth GAP profile test cases. For which the user should validate multiple scenarios(Both correct and incorrect pass key).

But now am not able to test it, because it doesn't prompt me for entering a pass key. Is there any settings to enable passkey support for Nexus4 and nexus 7

Comment: Sorry, you lost me here. I use a Nexus 4 and I had no problems entering a pass key during the initial pairing. Indeed it does not request that key for every connection, that would be more than annoying. Maybe try to delete any previous pairing and retry. As said: I had no problems with this.

Comment: Could you please let me know which Android version is it. 
I am using 4.2 version of Android in which Bluedroid is supported

Comment: Android 4.4.2 from the official updates.